# How to print from a data center?

Tags: network-printer, cloud

I have servers in a data center (Windows servers in a cloud-based service such as AWS or Azure), and they need to talk to dedicated office network printers. In other words, there will be processes running on the server that will need to send print jobs at any time of the day or night, so relying on an RDP connection to be up isn't what I'm looking for.
I know I can set up a VPN and then connect the printers directly, but are there any alternative reasonable, reliable, commonly-used methods? Would IPP (Internet Printing Protocol) be appropriate, or something else?

Comment: That's probably your best (secure) solution. Maybe other than that install something like Dropbox on your cloud and have it sync but everything else involves port forwarding or something gross security or convenience wise.

Comment: If you Remote Desktop to the servers using Windows Remote Desktop client then any printer connected to your local computer can be linked to the server without a VPN (if you can RDP to the machines without a VPN)... the Remote Desktop Client redirects your local printer install to the server and you should see `your_local_printer (redirected)` in `Devices and Printers` on the server... To add, using remote desktop without a VPN is still encrypted: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/03/12/top-10-rdp-protocol-misconceptions-part-2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

My main PC run on a public cloud my solution to printing comes down to one of three solutions.

Firstly, Using windows RDP to connect to the local printer defined on my local PC, this is the most frequently used method, it is baked in, secure and doesn't take any thinking about! If the printer is set up on the machine you connect from, it will appear in your printer folder over RDP (obviously this is only if you're Windows based)

Secondly, I use Google cloud print, again this runs through my local machine, if you log into chrome on both sides you can print through it (I only use this for Google docs printing, but I'm sure it can be configured to become the default printer in Windows)

Finally, I sync the documents to my local network and print directly. This is pretty rare but if I have specific printer settings etc its just easier this way sometimes.

For a while I did run a VPN into the cloud service, and could have run IPP through that, But RDP is secure and ultimately my machine is running in a cloud service, so if I trust that cloud I might as well trust Google with my print jobs!